# How to pass cursor rowtype between procedures in package

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an explicit cursor in package, I create rowtype based on this cursor, how can I pass this rowtype between procedures?
My exmaple hung up when compile.

```
cursor cur(param) is 
select * from dual where param = 1;
rec cur%rowtype;

procedure do_something_with_rec(p_rec in cur%rowtype)
is
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(p_rec.dummy);
end;

procedure main(param)
is
begin
 open cur(param);
 loop
   fetch into rec;
   exit when cur%notfound;
 end loop;
 close cur;

 do_something_with_rec(rec);
end;
```

Comment: If it's impossible, please advise structure in that I can pass data rowtype based not on table between procedures in package.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say it "hung up" (did you phone it?) but `cursor cur(param)` and `procedure main(param)` are missing datatypes.

Comment: I mean programm is stuck, google translate - "hung up" from russian "завис".

Comment: So it hangs or it fails? Two different things in computing.

Comment: It's hangs. My example above just is pseudo code. My source code is compiles well and dont fails but it's hangs and I found where is a mistake.
It's hangs on getClobVal, I write it without bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add parameter types in cursor, definition of procedure `main` and in `fetch` add cursor name. This package compiled and worked:

```
-- package

create or replace package p_test is

  procedure main(param in number);

end p_test;

-- body

create or replace package body p_test is

  cursor cur(param in number) is select * from dual where param = 1;
  rec cur%rowtype;

procedure do_something_with_rec(p_rec in cur%rowtype) is
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(p_rec.dummy);
end;

procedure main(param in number) is
begin
  open cur(param);
  loop
    fetch cur into rec;
    exit when cur%notfound;
  end loop;
  close cur;

  do_something_with_rec(rec);
end;
end p_test;
```

Comment: what i can see is that the cursor is global to the package, would it be possible to pass local cursor rowtype to any function or procedure available in the same package?